# Hide a button on click

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com

```
<apex:pageblockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!doToggleEditMode}" value="Edit" reRender="myPanel" rendered="{!NOT(bEditMode)}" id="c1" />
    <apex:commandButton action="{!doSave}" value="Save" reRender="myPanel" rendered="{!bEditMode}" />
    <apex:commandButton value="PRINT" onclick="window.print();"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="c2"/>
</apex:pageblockButtons>
```

**Extension**

```
public Boolean bEditMode {
get {
  if(bEditMode == null) {
      bEditmode = false;
      }
      return bEditMode;
  }
  set;
}

public PageReference doToggleEditMode() {
     bEditMode = !bEditMode;
        return null;
}

public PageReference doSave() {
    try {
    controller.save();
    doToggleEditMode();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
    }

    return null;
}
```

I want to hide my save button (id="c2") when some one click one the edit button. i tried using j query, but it does not work.(I have a toggle button. when you click on edit button it will change to save. in that case i have two save buttons. I want to hide one of them. ) Does anybody have any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a Visualforce $Component selector to get the actual DOM Id.
Something like:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!doToggleEditMode}" value="Edit" reRender="myPanel" 
  rendered="{!NOT(bEditMode)}" id="c1"
  onclick="document.getElementById('{!$Component.c2}').style.display='none';return true;" />
```

See also: [Best Practices for Accessing Component IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the help . But my problem is I have a toggle button. when you click on edit button it will change to save. in that case i have two save buttons. I want to hide one of them. So add your code to the edit button section. it will work but edit mode does not work.  do you know why?