# How to hide a button on click?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

I have a toggle buton call Edite. When I click on the Edite it will change to save and enable me to edite all the fileds. When edit button turn in to save i have two save buttons. So i want to Hide one of my save button name (Id = c2. ).

```
   <apex:pageblockButtons >
      <apex:commandButton action="{!doToggleEditMode}" value="Edit" reRender="myPanel" rendered="{!NOT(bEditMode)}" id="c1" />
      <apex:commandButton action="{!doSave}" value="Save" reRender="myPanel" rendered="{!bEditMode}" />
      <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="c2"/>
</apex:pageblockButtons>
```

I post this question yesterday and i got a answer saying

```
    <apex:commandButton action="{!doToggleEditMode}" value="Edit" reRender="myPanel" 
  rendered="{!NOT(bEditMode)}" id="c1"
  onclick="document.getElementById('{!$Component.c2}').style.display='none';return true;" />
```

This works,when i click on edit it will hide my save button but my toggle button does not work. It does not allow me to edit. Any body know why?

Comment: If I were you, I would try to attack it different way - have just one button and be able to recognize what behavior is expected from that button given current conditions. Having multiple buttons and hiding / showing them to me is a dirty way to do it - however I don't say it's not possible to get the effect as you want.

Comment: I see you asked a similar question in [Hide a button on click](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/82616/102). Please have a read of [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and